# Determine the density function and event probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can anyone help me with this problem, I can't figure out how to solve it...

> The distribution of a random variable $X$ is:
>
> $F(x)$ = \begin{cases} 1-e^{-2x},  & \text{if $x$ $\geq$  0 } \\ 0,
>  & \text{if $x$ < 0}  \\ \end{cases}
>
> Determine the density function. Determine the probability of the
>   following events:  $X$ > 2, −3 < $X$ ≤ 4.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done towards solving the problem? What do you know about the relationship between the distribution function and the density function?

Comment: **Hint:** $\Pr(X\gt 2)=1-\Pr(X\le 2)=1-F_X(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem?

$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} {f(x)dx}$, where f(x) is density function.
By definition, $F(a)=P(X\leq a)$, so $P(X>2)=1-P(x\leq 2)=1-F(2)$ and $P(-3 < X \leq 4)=P(X \leq 4)-P(X \leq -3)$